# How to align a label with wrapping tags?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I have a label and multiple tags that may wrap to multiple lines:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.label {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.boxes-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label class="label">Tags:</label>
  <span class="boxes-container">
      <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <label class="label">Tags:</label>
  <span class="boxes-container">
      <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to achieve the following:

1. The label and the first row of the tags should have the same middle line.
2. Get rid of the extra space below the last line of tags, but keep the space between the first and the second lines of tags.

Here is the desired outcome:

[image]

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I have set last and second last child's `margin-bottom` to `0px` and given `vertical-align: middle` to `.label` with line-height equal to the height of `.box`.

```css
.container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.label {
  margin-right: 10px;
  line-height:40px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.boxes-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box:last-child,.box:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label class="label">Tags:</label>
  <span class="boxes-container">
      <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <label class="label">Tags:</label>
  <span class="boxes-container">
      <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer. It's often helpful to the readers if you added some explanation with the answer as well.

Comment: yes sure,next time i will be careful about that,by the way i have added last and second last child's margin:0 and label give vertical align middle with line-height

Comment: There I have copied the explanation from your comment to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I have added css i.e.

```
.boxes-container .box:nth-last-of-type(-n+2) {
   margin-bottom: 0;
}
.label {  
   margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.label {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.boxes-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.boxes-container .box:nth-last-of-type(-n+2) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label class="label">Tags:</label>
  <span class="boxes-container">
      <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <label class="label">Tags:</label>
  <span class="boxes-container">
      <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out there are multiple ways of solving this. Here is yet another using `flex` to align your label:

```
.label {
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Assuming the height of your boxes is fixed we can set `.label` to the same height and center its content using flex. An equally effective one-line solution is to specify `line-height: 40px`, assuming your label content will not wrap to multiple lines.

My original solution to remove the empty space following each `.boxes-container`'s last two elements can be seen in my [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/Misacorp/pen/aLwPyb), but [ankita patel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499680/how-to-align-a-label-with-wrapping-tags/46499723#46499723) uses a rather elegant expression to cover the last and second-last `.box` element:

```
.box:nth-last-of-type(-n+2)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be to play with *margins* (note that an *nth-child solution* will not work if the *wrapping* changes):

1. Add `margin: 5px` to the `box` to replace the 10px right and bottom margins.
2. Now for the container `boxes-container` you can give *negative* `margin: -5px` to pull the `box`es to the edges.

That sorts out everything except the alignment of the `label`. In the current markup, there is no general fix that will dynamically work for all `box` sizes and `box-container` widths - so you can give some `margin-top` to align it.

See demo below:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.label {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px; /* adjust this*/
}

.boxes-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -5px; /* NEW */
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 60px;
  /*margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;*/
  margin: 5px; /* NEW */
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label class="label">Tags:</label>
  <span class="boxes-container">
      <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <label class="label">Tags:</label>
  <span class="boxes-container">
      <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```